# Swiper next/prev doesn't load item image when looped

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I'm facing a problem with swiper and the layout I need to create. It have the first image bigger than the others. I tried to make it work with one single slider but it miscalculate the animations and the slider numbers.

So I created two separated sliders that connect:
[image: Main highlighted with red: single image, fade effect, and thumbnail, single image with overflow visible and negative margin with same slide size to underlay the first item:]

The problem is that the swiper thumbnail doesn't load the next/prev loop item correctly, only load when I drag. And when reach the last item, it doesn't create the next/prev looped item.

Here's a gif with the behavior:
[image: Loop next items not creating]

Here's a pen:
https://codepen.io/giovancruz/pen/wvORgXL

```js
const slidesWrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".js-slides-wrapper");

if (slidesWrapper) {
  slidesWrapper.forEach((wrapper) => {
    /* check if slider exists */
    const mainSliderElement = wrapper.querySelector(".js-main-slider");
    const thumbnailSliderElement = wrapper.querySelector(
      ".js-thumbnail-slider"
    );

    let thumbnailSlider = null;

    /* instantiate main slider */
    const mainslider = new Swiper(mainSliderElement, {
      loop: true,
      effect: "fade",
      speed: 0
    });

    /* instantiate thumbnail slider */
    if (thumbnailSliderElement) {
      thumbnailSlider = new Swiper(thumbnailSliderElement, {
        loop: true,
        spaceBetween: 20,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        navigation: {
          prevEl: wrapper.querySelector(".js-prev"),
          nextEl: wrapper.querySelector(".js-next")
        }
      });
    }

    /* Connect both slides */
    if (thumbnailSlider && mainslider) {
      thumbnailSlider.controller.control = mainslider;
      mainslider.controller.control = thumbnailSlider;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

.slides-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.25rem;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
}
.slides-wrapper .swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  gap: 20px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.slides-wrapper .image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 430px;
  background-color: #ededed;
}
.slides-wrapper .image .img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  -o-object-position: center;
  object-position: center;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.slides-wrapper .main-slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slides-wrapper .main-slider-wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.slides-wrapper .main-slider-wrapper .main-slider {
  width: 100%;
}
.slides-wrapper .main-slider-wrapper .main-slider .image {
  height: 600px;
}
.slides-wrapper .main-slider-wrapper .main-slider .slide {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
.slides-wrapper .main-slider-wrapper .main-slider .slide.swiper-slide-active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.slides-wrapper .thumb-slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}
.slides-wrapper .thumb-slider-wrapper .thumbnail-slider {
  width: 330px;
  overflow: unset;
  margin-left: -350px;
}
.slides-wrapper .thumb-slider-wrapper .swiper-controls {
  gap: 15px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reset-css@5.0.2/reset.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/11.0.5/swiper-bundle.min.css">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/11.0.5/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="slides-wrapper js-slides-wrapper">
      <div class="main-slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slider product-slider swiper main-slider js-main-slider">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="slide swiper-slide">
              <figure class="image">
                <picture class="picture">
                  <img decoding="async" width="300" height="200" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="img" alt="" srcset="https://placehold.co/600x400 300w" sizes="(max-width: 100%)" loading="lazy" title="">
                </picture>
    
              </figure>
    
              <a class="button product-title style-secondary" target="" title="Dummy Product 3" aria-label="Dummy Product 3"> <span class="button-wrapper">
                <strong class="button-text">Dummy Product 3</strong>
    
                <span class="icon-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
                  <span class="button-icon">
                    <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="12" viewBox="0 0 16 12" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.058 4.16867L10.8892 0L6.7205 4.16867L7.37158 4.81974L10.4287 1.7627V11.0792H0V12H11.3494V1.76232L14.4069 4.81974L15.058 4.16867Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide swiper-slide">
              <figure class="image">
                <picture class="picture">
                  <img decoding="async" width="300" height="200" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="img" alt="" srcset="https://placehold.co/600x400 300w" sizes="(max-width: 100%)" loading="lazy" title="">
                </picture>
    
              </figure>
    
              <a class="button product-title style-secondary" target="" title="Dummy Product 5" aria-label="Dummy Product 5"> <span class="button-wrapper">
                <strong class="button-text">Dummy Product 5</strong>
    
                <span class="icon-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
                  <span class="button-icon">
                    <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="12" viewBox="0 0 16 12" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.058 4.16867L10.8892 0L6.7205 4.16867L7.37158 4.81974L10.4287 1.7627V11.0792H0V12H11.3494V1.76232L14.4069 4.81974L15.058 4.16867Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide swiper-slide">
              <figure class="image">
                <picture class="picture">
                  <img decoding="async" width="300" height="200" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="img" alt="" srcset="https://placehold.co/600x400 300w" sizes="(max-width: 100%)" loading="lazy" title="">
                </picture>
    
              </figure>
    
              <a class="button product-title style-secondary" target="" title="Dummy Product 6" aria-label="Dummy Product 6"> <span class="button-wrapper">
                <strong class="button-text">Dummy Product 6</strong>
    
                <span class="icon-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
                  <span class="button-icon">
                    <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="12" viewBox="0 0 16 12" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.058 4.16867L10.8892 0L6.7205 4.16867L7.37158 4.81974L10.4287 1.7627V11.0792H0V12H11.3494V1.76232L14.4069 4.81974L15.058 4.16867Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide swiper-slide">
              <figure class="image">
                <picture class="picture">
                  <img decoding="async" width="300" height="200" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="img" alt="" srcset="https://placehold.co/600x400 300w" sizes="(max-width: 100%)" loading="lazy" title="">
                </picture>
    
              </figure>
    
              <a class="button product-title style-secondary" target="" title="Dummy Product 1" aria-label="Dummy Product 1"> <span class="button-wrapper">
                <strong class="button-text">Dummy Product 1</strong>
    
                <span class="icon-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
                  <span class="button-icon">
                    <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="12" viewBox="0 0 16 12" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.058 4.16867L10.8892 0L6.7205 4.16867L7.37158 4.81974L10.4287 1.7627V11.0792H0V12H11.3494V1.76232L14.4069 4.81974L15.058 4.16867Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="thumb-slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slider product-slider swiper thumbnail-slider js-thumbnail-slider" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="slide swiper-slide">
              <figure class="image">
                <picture class="picture">
                  <img decoding="async" width="300" height="200" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="img" alt="" srcset="https://placehold.co/600x400 300w" sizes="(max-width: 100%)" loading="lazy" title="">
                </picture>
    
              </figure>
    
              <a class="button product-title style-secondary" target="" title="Dummy Product 3" aria-label="Dummy Product 3"> <span class="button-wrapper">
                <strong class="button-text">Dummy Product 3</strong>
    
                <span class="icon-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
                  <span class="button-icon">
                    <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="12" viewBox="0 0 16 12" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.058 4.16867L10.8892 0L6.7205 4.16867L7.37158 4.81974L10.4287 1.7627V11.0792H0V12H11.3494V1.76232L14.4069 4.81974L15.058 4.16867Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide swiper-slide">
              <figure class="image">
                <picture class="picture">
                  <img decoding="async" width="300" height="200" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="img" alt="" srcset="https://placehold.co/600x400 300w" sizes="(max-width: 100%)" loading="lazy" title="">
                </picture>
    
              </figure>
    
              <a class="button product-title style-secondary" target="" title="Dummy Product 5" aria-label="Dummy Product 5"> <span class="button-wrapper">
                <strong class="button-text">Dummy Product 5</strong>
    
                <span class="icon-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
                  <span class="button-icon">
                    <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="12" viewBox="0 0 16 12" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.058 4.16867L10.8892 0L6.7205 4.16867L7.37158 4.81974L10.4287 1.7627V11.0792H0V12H11.3494V1.76232L14.4069 4.81974L15.058 4.16867Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide swiper-slide">
              <figure class="image">
                <picture class="picture">
                  <img decoding="async" width="300" height="200" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="img" alt="" srcset="https://placehold.co/600x400 300w" sizes="(max-width: 100%)" loading="lazy" title="">
                </picture>
    
              </figure>
    
              <a class="button product-title style-secondary" target="" title="Dummy Product 6" aria-label="Dummy Product 6"> <span class="button-wrapper">
                <strong class="button-text">Dummy Product 6</strong>
    
                <span class="icon-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
                  <span class="button-icon">
                    <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="12" viewBox="0 0 16 12" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.058 4.16867L10.8892 0L6.7205 4.16867L7.37158 4.81974L10.4287 1.7627V11.0792H0V12H11.3494V1.76232L14.4069 4.81974L15.058 4.16867Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide swiper-slide">
              <figure class="image">
                <picture class="picture">
                  <img decoding="async" width="300" height="200" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" class="img" alt="" srcset="https://placehold.co/600x400 300w" sizes="(max-width: 100%)" loading="lazy" title="">
                </picture>
    
              </figure>
    
              <a class="button product-title style-secondary" target="" title="Dummy Product 1" aria-label="Dummy Product 1"> <span class="button-wrapper">
                <strong class="button-text">Dummy Product 1</strong>
    
                <span class="icon-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
                  <span class="button-icon">
                    <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="12" viewBox="0 0 16 12" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15.058 4.16867L10.8892 0L6.7205 4.16867L7.37158 4.81974L10.4287 1.7627V11.0792H0V12H11.3494V1.76232L14.4069 4.81974L15.058 4.16867Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="controls swiper-controls js-controls"><button class="icon button prev js-prev has-style style-light"> <span class="icon-wrapper">
          <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="17" height="12" viewBox="0 0 17 12" fill="currentColor">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.7928 6.35358H0V5.35358H14.7929L10.1464 0.707107L10.8535 0L16.7071 5.85355L10.8535 11.7071L10.1464 11L14.7928 6.35358Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
          </svg>
          </span>
    
          <span class="sr-only">Return to previous slide</span>
    
          </button>
          <button class="icon button next js-next has-style style-light"> <span class="icon-wrapper">
            <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="17" height="12" viewBox="0 0 17 12" fill="currentColor">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M14.7928 6.35358H0V5.35358H14.7929L10.1464 0.707107L10.8535 0L16.7071 5.85355L10.8535 11.7071L10.1464 11L14.7928 6.35358Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
            </svg>
            </span>
    
            <span class="sr-only">Jump to next slide</span>
    
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough to fix it, you may need to define responsive slidesPerView as you want.

The reason why it's happening is probably because Swiper can't understand you are next to the end of the visible items because of your negative margin on the swiper wrapper.

If you need that css, try to set it on a new wrapper instead of the same as the one with .swiper class.

```js
thumbnailSlider = new Swiper(thumbnailSliderElement, {
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 20,
  slidesPerView: 3,
  navigation: {
    prevEl: wrapper.querySelector(".js-prev"),
    nextEl: wrapper.querySelector(".js-next")
  }
});
```

```css
 .thumbnail-slider {
    width: 100%;
  }
```